# Can a scripting / programming language be a functional requirement for a website?

Tags: php, perl, html, apache

I make websites for a living. I've always used scripting languages (DCL, Perl, now mostly PHP) to enhance my productivity (templating for easy changes), even if a site was relatively static.

I'm now working with a group that wants me to render out static files as they view scripting languages as a security threat.

I'm not looking to start a debate, just wondering if there are potential future requirements for a non-interactive (no login, personalization, or database to pull from) that would require the use of a server side scripting language. They do allow apache includes, but these are lacking the features of a true programming language in my experience.

So Stack Overflow, what limitations could I potentially run into if I don't have a scripting language available to me? Can everything I would want to do for this type of site really be accomplished sans a server side programming language?

Comment: Why does "not looking to start a debate" always end up being one?

Comment: You, Sir, are dealing with ID10Ts...

Comment: It really depends on what "everything" includes ..

Answer (score 2):

You could just build it dynamically while you develop and then copy the html into a new folder and upload the html generated by the php?

That would allow you to keep your work flow of having header/footer in its own file, but would add an extra step.

Comment: Yes, I am considering doing this. My question was more meant to find out if there are any clear disadvantages to doing this. Is anything *NOT* possible this way?

Comment: Obviously the answer is yes... many things are not possible without a server side language. Technologies will allow you to get around things that us't to be server side only(AJAX, JSON, ect.) but in my opinion that is actually less secure since you are allowing the whole world to see your code instead of hiding it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course its possible to have websites (oh good old times) purely static.

There would be ways/jobs that render the pages (in any language) depending on other content (database, files) once a day and upload the changes to the ftp hosting the "pure" html sites.

That is a bit rough, since everyone finds dynamic stuff fency, but only showing off stuff about your company is pretty static to me... 
the end user does not care much about how the info is procued: at runtime via a script language or already finished as html docs on a ftp.

I am not saying that good security configuration could kill threads and its a good idea for everyone... but its still a way to go ;-)